# Are questions on fanfictions on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Can somebody ask a question about a certain fanfiction here and it be on topic? For example, I'd like to ask a question about *Harry Potter and the Vanguards of Magic*. Is this an on-topic subject here?

Comment: As the duplicate says, fanfiction *is* on-topic, so you can ask about it. That said, a lot of fanfiction is obscure, badly-written, or both, so you may or may not get good answers, depending on your choice of fanfic.

Comment: Also, often fanfic questions get downvoted for other reasons, especially so if they're borderline pornography or have weird fetish elements

Comment: @Valorum Like most Drarry fanfics that have flooded the site in recent times!

Comment: @Rebel-Scum - Mpreg and rape fantasy fics seem to particularly rile people